# Fastest connection for tomcat 9.0 in 2021: NIO or APR?

Tags: tomcat, nio, tomcat9, apr

I'm installing a server that's going to be mostly transferring files over 16MiB, and upload/download speed for individual transfers will be essential, but no more than say 100 connections at once. We have a backend that uses a custom UDP connection, but the failover is to HTTP/TCP so I want to make sure that's fast too

The web server is Apache Tomcat 9.0 and I've installed the APR library so my SSL connector in `$CATALINA_HOME/conf/server.xml` is working with either
`protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"`
or
`protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"`
and then
`<UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol" />`

But I'm finding conflicting information online about which is a better choice on something like Tomcat 9.0.52. It's running in a Debian 11 VM if that changes anything.

This seems to be related [Tomcat with APR still says aprConnector is false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49809345)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56976281/2834978

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using HTTPS you actually have 5 choices: NIO+JSSE, NIO+OpenSSL, NIO2+JSSE, NIO2+OpenSSL, APR+OpenSSL.

From a [presentation by Jean-Frederic Clere](http://events17.linuxfoundation.org/sites/events/files/slides/TomcatOpenSSL.pdf) at ApacheCon 2017 you can see that:

- OpenSSL beats JSSE by an order of magnitude,
- NIO vs NIO2 vs APR performance is very similar, but Java implementations usually end up on top.

Since the default configuration of the `AprLifecycleListener` is equivalent to:

```xml
<Listener SSLEngine="on" FIPSMode="off" SSLRandomSeed="builtin"
          useAprConnector="false" useOpenSSL="true"
          className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener"/>
```

you'll get NIO+OpenSSL by default whenever the Tomcat Native Library is detected in your system.