# Spring application and external tomcat server HTTP2

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, postman, http2

When I deploy a spring boot application on an external tomcat server, do I need to configure `HTTP2` on the tomcat server as well my spring boot application? I am a bit confused here about how the communication occurs when I call my spring application deployed inside of `Tomcat` via the browser or any other client say, `Postman`.

I have enabled `HTTP2` on Tomcat and verified the same:

```
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [08/Jan/2023:18:28:44 +0530] "GET / HTTP/2.0" 200 11408
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [08/Jan/2023:18:28:44 +0530] "GET /tomcat.svg HTTP/2.0" 200 68761
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [08/Jan/2023:18:28:44 +0530] "GET /tomcat.css HTTP/2.0" 200 5895
```

and I have configured my spring boot application to use `HTTP2` as well using the steps mentioned in this [link](https://byte27.com/guides/using-http-2-in-your-spring-boot-application/).

When I am calling my `RestController` deployed in the external tomcat, I am still getting `HTTP 1.1`

```
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Jan/2023:23:41:26 +0530] "HEAD /demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/ HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Jan/2023:23:41:51 +0530] "HEAD /demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/getMessage HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

where `demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT` is the deployed artifact.

I verified the same using `curl`

```
HTTP/1.1 200
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 41
Date: Sun, 08 Jan 2023 18:11:51 GMT
```

What am I missing here?

My `application.properties` file looks like:

```
# configuring SSL
server.port=8443
server.ssl.key-store-type=pkcs12
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:springboot.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password=password
server.ssl.key-alias=springboot

# enabling http2
server.http2.enabled=true
```

and I have created the `Keystore` correctly using the following command:

```
keytool -genkeypair -alias springboot -keyalg RSA -keysize 4096 -storetype PKCS12 -keystore springboot.p12 -validity 3650 -storepass password
```

[image]

**EDIT 1:**
Spring Boot version - 2.7.2
Tomcat server - 9.0.70

In my `server.xml`, I have commented and edited the following `Connector`:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               maxThreads="200" SSLEnabled="true">
        <UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol" />
        <SSLHostConfig>
            <Certificate certificateKeystoreFile="ssl/tomcat.jks"
                         certificateKeyAlias="tomcat"
                         certificateKeystorePassword="password"
                         type="RSA" />
        </SSLHostConfig>
    </Connector>
```

which has helped me enable `TLS` as well as `HTTP2` both on Tomcat. The problem is when I am deploying a spring boot application and making rest calls to that application's `RestController`, I am getting `HTTP1.1` response. Making calls to `Tomcat` webservices is giving correct `HTTP2` response.

Comment: is this `spring-boot 3` app or `spring-boot 2` app?

Comment: spring-boot 2.7.2 and tomcat 9.0.70

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomcat as standalone sever has by default in it's `sever.xml` disabled the connector for `http 2`.

### Spring Boot 2, up to Tomcat 9

If this is a `spring boot 2` deployed as war application then this could be using up to `Tomcat 9`.

You must find your [Tomcat 9 (Server.xml) connector for http2](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/9.0.x/conf/server.xml#L102) under the deployed server `conf` directory and uncomment this connector, while also providing the necessary certificate files.

You need to uncomment the

> ```
>    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"
>                maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" >
>         <UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol" />
>         <SSLHostConfig>
>             <Certificate certificateKeyFile="conf/localhost-rsa-key.pem"
>                          certificateFile="conf/localhost-rsa-cert.pem"
>                          certificateChainFile="conf/localhost-rsa-chain.pem"
>                          type="RSA" />
>         </SSLHostConfig>
>     </Connector>
> ```

### Spring Boot 3, Tomcat 10 or later

In case you have a `spring boot 3` deployed as war application then this should be using `Tomcat 10` or later.

You must find your [Tomcat 10 (Server.xml) connector for http2](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/10.0.x/conf/server.xml#L86) under the deployed server `conf` directory and uncomment while also providing the necessary certificate file.

> ```
> <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
>                maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true">
>         <UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol" />
>         <SSLHostConfig>
>             <Certificate certificateKeystoreFile="conf/localhost-rsa.jks"
>                          type="RSA" />
>         </SSLHostConfig>
>     </Connector>
> ```

Comment: As per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68810106/fastest-connection-for-tomcat-9-0-in-2021-nio-or-apr, I can go ahead with NIO protocol. Should I use APR? I am not using Tomcat native binaries. I have normal distribution version downloaded. Hope that helps.

Added spring boot and tomcat versions

Comment: @Adithya as you can see this can be opinion based question. Check the documentation and then decide which suits you better.

Comment: That's fine. I am currently using NIO as mentioned in my edits. My issue as I mentioned is with spring boot applications rest controller. Tomcat network calls are already showing HTTP2 protocol correctly.

Comment: @Adithya share the curl commands you execute both for tomcat and for application web services that return `http1.1` vs `http2`

Comment: curl -k -sI https://localhost:8443/
curl -k -sI https://localhost:8443/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. While deploying a spring boot application on external tomcat there is no need to specify Server `SSL` and `HTTP2` parameters in the spring properties file as `Tomcat` will handle all the `HTTPS` requests. I was trying to mix 2 things.

Configuring the Spring Boot application to support HTTP2 will work if we are deploying using an embedded Tomcat server and I was able to verify that with Chrome browser.

As of writing this post, Postman still doesn't support `HTTP2` requests, hence, I was seeing `HTTP 1.1` protocol in the `Tomcat` access log. The same thing I believe is the issue with `curl` request. As my certificate is self-signed, I am using options `-k` and `-sI`. Maybe that's the reason, I am getting the response :

```
HTTP/1.1 200
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Tue, 10 Jan 2023 18:09:29 GMT
```

when running `curl -k -sI https://localhost:8443`. I will figure out why I am getting `HTTP 1.1` and update it here.

Sharing this answer to help anyone coming across this question next time.

Comment: the chrome extension `Talend Api Tester` support https and ssl. You may try with it as well

Comment: thanks! will try. Although a normal `https` call shows `h2` protocol in Network tab.